# How to add a line in many files

Tags: text-processing, vim, regular-expression

I have many **.html** files and I need to add a meta tag after <**head**>'s start tag in each file.

How I can do that?

Is `vim`suited for the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `vim`, you can do:

```
:%s/<head\b[^>]*>/& <meta foo="bar">/g
```

You could also do this in GNU `sed`, which would possibly be more fitting:

```
for file in *.html; do
    sed -i 's/<head\b[^>]*>/& <meta foo="bar">/g' "$file"
done
```

Be warned, `-i` breaks symlinks.

Comment: for file in *.html; do sed -i 's/<head[^>*>/& <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>/g'; done

Comment: this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 90: unterminated `s' command

Comment: `sed -i.bkp` it will edit original files, and also take backup as filename.bkp

Comment: If that HTML is HTML5, your regular expression will erroneously match [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html) tags too. Make it match only if “head” ends at word boundary.

Comment: @manatwork Good catch! Will fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/ a\
    Line which you want to append' filename
```

for this example

```
sed -i '/<HEAD>/a <meta>' test.txt
<HEAD>
<HEAD>
```

Result :

```
<HEAD>
<meta>
</HEAD>
```

The above command will append new line after the string get matched. However this will give wrong result if file has input string as

```
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
```

Result:

```
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
<meta>
</HEAD>  //which is wrong.
```

May be we can try this approach:

```
sed -i 's/<HEAD>/<HEAD><meta>/' filename
```

Comment: `<head><foo>` is legal in HTML, so this will not work as expected if such a condition exists. For example, this would result in `<head><foo>\n<meta ...>` in such a case.

Comment: Sorry chris..i didn't noticed that bug..thanks